# cannot resolve provider android:name

Tags: android, cannot-find-symbol

i cant seem to figure this out here is the android manifest.xml code that i edited. it keeps saying that .NotesProvider attached to android:name cannot be resolved

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:authorities="com.mizer.spizer.mizer.com.spizer.mizer.evaluation.notesprovider"
        android:name=".NotesProvider"
        android:exported="false" />

</application>
```

Comment: Did you try to delete the dot? "." or adding the full declaration: "com.mizer.spizer.mizer.com.spizer.mizer.evaluation.NotesProvider" like this? BTW, check your package name inside the provider. Is that long? you repeat the package there.

Comment: yes i know that was a mistake i made when i created a copy of a package inside of a main package and now i cant really get rid of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of your provider list does not appear to be correct.  Multiple authorities must be separated with a semicolon. It seems you have duplicate authorities in the list, or you have multiple authorities that are not separated with a semicolon.

See Google developer documentation on using the provider element here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html

Scroll down to the first attribute 'Android:authorities'